# Is it possible to change the code in the program itself in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, private, theory, friend

About the last year I did Java(Android)-programming, and did C# the Year before that. About a month now I'm learning C++, and since I got over friends, inheritance and stuff, I got a few questions, since I haven't been working with it up until now:

Is there a way for a class to define friends later on, because they need to exchange information or something. e.g. is there a way to define a 'random' friend later on? what do you need for that? The function's name or the address of the class?

Or is there generally a way to change the code from the program itself, so that it won't be necessary to recompile? e.g. creating new functions, classes or so?

I'd be very happy about any answer about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is not possible with C++.  If you need that sort of dynamically changing the program, you are better advised using a more dynamic higher-level language like Lisp.

`friend`s can only be added to a class by modifying its source code.  This is a feature, not a bug.

Comment: okay, so could I create an instance modifying the source code, compiling it new and closing itself? I'd need a external file having all the temporary stuff included, but would it work?

Comment: What you are trying to do sounds most weird. You should probably step back a few steps and take a broader look at your problem.  A better solution that fits the spirit of C++ will surely appear.  If you think that modifying the program at run-time is a cool thing and you just *want* to do it, I'm afraid you'll have to leave C++ in favor of a language that was designed to do this.  C++ wasn't.

Comment: Eh No, I actually don't want to do this, but I wanted to know if it was (theoretically) possible, to understand it's complexity for further programming

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to extend functionality like that.

1. Use dynamically loaded modules with the extended functionality. These modules supply a specific interface, and can be compiled separately from the main program.
2. Add support for scripting - allow users to add write scripts, and run them from inside your program.

The first solution is easier, depending on how much control you want to give those scripts.

Comment: I see. so the main program would need to restart if I want to modify it's code. or could I create a second Instance changing the first, and vice versa?